# Insert new item into object PyMongo

Tags: pymongo

I'm creating a system where I need to add entries to an object in a MongoDB database. This is the database structure I'm kind of working with:

```py
{
"Object":{
    "name":"description"
}
```

From the research I've done, I've found a way to change the value, but not add something **into** the "Object" object. How would I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to reference the object with sub-keys followed
by the value to update in the `$set` update operator.

Example:

```
collection.update_one({
     <Find-Filter>
}, {
     "$set": {
          "Object.createdAt": datetime.now(),
          "Object.anotherKey": "someValue",
          "Object.subObject.subObjKey": "subObjValue",
     }
})
```

This will update the document to the following.

```
{
"Object":{
    "name":"description",
    "createdAt": ISODate("2021-03-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "anotherKey": "someValue",
    "subObject": {
         "subObjKey": "subObjValue",
    },
}
```